# Rspec integration test: Routes not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, integration-testing

I was trying to write an integration test testing, if my controller raises a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exeption for deleted articles (which are just marked as deleted):

```
it "should return 404 for deleted articles" do
  @article = Factory :article, :status => "deleted"
  expect { get edit_article_path(:id => @article.id) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
end
```

These kind of tests work fine in a controller spec, but inside of the spec/requests I get this error:

```
expected ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, got #<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles", :id=>595}>
```

So it looks up my routes correctly (since it knows the controller etc.) but still raises the error. Why is that?

Thanks, Johannes

Comment: In my spec tests, I usually use `visit` instead of Rest verbs (I use capybara). Does it change something for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this test is in your `spec/controllers` directory, then the `get` method you're calling isn't expecting a path, it's expecting a symbol for the controller action you want to call. So you'd need to change the `expect` line to something like:

```
expect { get :edit, :id => @article.id }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

Take a look at the [RSpec Controller Spec documentation](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) for more info.

Comment: good catch and +1 ;) Capybara is more flexible with it's `visit` keyword.